# How to change Symfony2 security plaintext encoders from User to User Interface

Tags: security, symfony, fosuserbundle, plaintext

I'm trying to crate a chain provider for login form in my Symfony2 application (version 2.3) - this is my security Yaml:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
        providers: [in_memory, fos_userbundle]
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    in_memory:
        memory:
        users:
            admin: { password: god, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
        provider: chain_provider
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
        security: true

    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/group/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

As you can see, I'm using FOSUserBundle (great stuff btw).

The problem is that after I login with in_memory admin user, I can't get to the /profile/ URL. I'm getting this error msg:

```
AccessDeniedHttpException: This user does not have access to this section
```

I found a cause to this - the problem is in FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController class:

```
public function showAction()
{
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Profile:show.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'), array('user' => $user));
}
```

The Controller is checking if $user object is an instance of UserInterface, which is not, because it is instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User (plaintext encoder class).

I tried to change encoder configuration to this:

```
security:
    encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface: plaintext
```

But it didn't work. I found that the User class is hardcoded in numerous places with the Symfony engine.

So my question is: how to change that behaviour from security yaml? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but you cant see the profile of memory user's. Profile is made only for FOS users. Thats why it must implement `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface`.

Answer (score 3):

[PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/language.operators.type.php):

> instanceof is smart enough to know that a class that implements an
>   interface is an instance of the interface

[Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/User.html) implements [AdvancedUserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/AdvancedUserInterface.html) which implements [UserInterface](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html).

Your problem is not the `typeof` check in `FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController` but a wrong firewall configuration or the in-memory user not receiving it's roles correctly!